# Why is my GCP app engine not splitting traffic correctly?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to split traffic in my Python3 application using Flask. I create two different versions of the app using `gcloud app deploy -v1` and `gcloud app deploy -v2` and then split the traffic evenly using `gcloud app services set-traffic myservice --splits=v1=0.5,v2=0.5 --split-by ip`. I've made several requests to `myservice` but I only ever see the output from `v2` of my app.

The [GCP documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/splitting-traffic?authuser=2&_ga=2.117233542.-1614398834.1626655508#gcloud) here suggests that the issue might be related to caching and says: "For cacheable static resources that vary between versions, change the resource's URL between versions."

I cannot figure out how to change the target url to serve these two versions in different locations. I am not sure if this is something that needs to be done in the app.yaml file or my flask application?

For reference, here is my `app.yaml` file:

```
# Copyright 2021 Google LLC
#
# Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
# you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
# You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.

service: myservice
runtime: python39
env: standard
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT main:app

runtime_config:
  python_version: 3


# This sample incurs costs to run on the App Engine flexible environment. 
# The settings below are to reduce costs during testing and are not appropriate
# for production use. For more information, see:
# https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml
manual_scaling:
  instances: 1
resources:
  cpu: 1
  memory_gb: 0.5
  disk_size_gb: 10
```

Here is v1 of my app:

```
# Copyright 2015 Google Inc. All Rights Reserved.
#
# Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
# you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
# You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.

# [START gae_flex_quickstart]
import logging

from flask import Flask


app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def hello():
    """Return a friendly HTTP greeting."""
    return 'Hello world!'


@app.errorhandler(500)
def server_error(e):
    logging.exception('An error occurred during a request.')
    return """
    An internal error occurred: <pre>{}</pre>
    See logs for full stacktrace.
    """.format(e), 500


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # This is used when running locally. Gunicorn is used to run the
    # application on Google App Engine. See entrypoint in app.yaml.
    app.run(host='127.0.0.1', port=8080, debug=True)
# [END gae_flex_quickstart]
```

and finally `v2` of my app:

```
# Copyright 2015 Google Inc. All Rights Reserved.
#
# Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
# you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
# You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.

# [START gae_flex_quickstart]
import logging

from flask import Flask


app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def hello():
    """Return a friendly HTTP greeting."""
    return 'Hello Universe!'


@app.errorhandler(500)
def server_error(e):
    logging.exception('An error occurred during a request.')
    return """
    An internal error occurred: <pre>{}</pre>
    See logs for full stacktrace.
    """.format(e), 500


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # This is used when running locally. Gunicorn is used to run the
    # application on Google App Engine. See entrypoint in app.yaml.
    app.run(host='127.0.0.1', port=8080, debug=True)
# [END gae_flex_quickstart]
```

Comment: You are using ` --split-by ip`, so if you are making all the requests from the same IP, they will be always routed to the same service. Even routing from a different IP (unless you tried a lot of them) can make the request go to the `v2` version again. So try to use the cookie-based splitting to route to the other version.

Comment: I think @yedpodtrzitko has correctly indicated one problem with your testing strategy. There are several ways to test traffic splitting. Use an Internet service that uses distributed clients to test your application or one of the uptime services that tests from multiple geographic locations.